Winapi.Perception.hpp is missing for Rad Studio 12
I'm trying to compile a part of the firefox source code using C++ builder. Specifically the SMTC integration. This requires WinAPI.Media.hpp. But almost all WindowsRT units require Winapi.Perception.hpp. Which cannot be found.
This file should theoretically be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\include\windows\rtl, but I double checked and It's nowhere to be found.
I also tried creating a blank project with the following line in the header:
#include <WinAPI.Media.hpp>

But same issue. Something must have gone wrong with my installation.
What can I do to fix this issue? Does anyone else have this file?

My RADStusio 12 installation does not have Winapi.Perception.hpp, either. But Firefox is not written in C++Builder, so why do you think you need C++Builder-specific header files to compile it?

@RemyLebeau I am aware Firefox is not built in C++ builder. I just took a source file from the Firefox source code to write a library, as I wanted to integrate a feature the browser has in my own application. Specifically WindowsSMTCProvider.cpp and WindowsSMTCProvider.h files.

I reached out to Embarcadero and they have confirmed that this is a bug in the installer as it does not include this file. I have opened a ticket:
RSS-2106: Winapi.Perception.hpp is missing
They say that they will make a copy of Winapi.Perception.hpp available for download soon.

UPDATE: Embarcadero has posted a temporary download until a more formal fix is released:
https://etsfftp01.embarcadero.com/?u=uRvF&p=33CV&path=/Winapi.Perception.hpp.zip

This is great to hear. On a side note, I cannot access the link you attached. I get the errror "No Access. You do not have permission to view this request."

The link works fine. If you are newly registered then the access error is a known issue: "If you just registered for the portal it needs some time to get you attached to the proper group. To speed that up you can file a new issue yourself."
